# ReactJS change url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make weather app with react, and I want to change city by typing the `name` of the city in `input`. I have function that must change state:

```
 update( e ){
      this.setState({cityName: e.target.value})
    }
```

And in render function I have this:

```
return <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
                    <input type="text"
                    onChange={this.update.bind(this)}/>
                    <div className="panel-list">{ persons }</div>
                    <h1>{this.state.coord.lon}</h1>
                    <h1>{this.state.cityName}</h1>       //output my city name
```

And I have function where I pass my city name var in URL to api:

```
UserList(city = this.state.cityName){
      let apiKey = 'c24bda9c5812d6be82860b70c35d41a5';
      let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
      let weatherURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&appid=c24bda9c5812d6be82860b70c35d41a5';
    return $.getJSON(weatherURL).then((response) => {
        this.setState({coord: response.coord});
        this.setState({person: response.weather});
    });
  }
        </div>
```

But it not change weather forecast. Why it not changes?
All code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {
      person: [],
        coord: [],
        cityName: 'London'
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.UserList();
    }

    update( e ){
      this.setState({cityName: e.target.value})
    }

  UserList(city = this.state.cityName){
      let apiKey = 'c24bda9c5812d6be82860b70c35d41a5';
      let url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
      let weatherURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+'&appid=c24bda9c5812d6be82860b70c35d41a5';
    return $.getJSON(weatherURL).then((response) => {
        this.setState({coord: response.coord});
        this.setState({person: response.weather});
    });
  }

    render() {
        const persons = this.state.person.map((item) => {
            return <div>
              <h1>{item['id']}</h1>
              <span>{item['main']}</span>

            </div>
        });

        return <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
                    <input type="text"
                    onChange={this.update.bind(this)}/>
                    <div className="panel-list">{ persons }</div>
                    <h1>{this.state.coord.lon}</h1>
                    <h1>{this.state.cityName}</h1>
        </div>
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentDidMount` will only be called one time in the components lifecycle - right after the component is initially mounted. If you want your `update` method to trigger `UserList`, you need to call `UserList` after your `setState` call completes in `update`

```
update( e ){
  this.setState({cityName: e.target.value}, () => {
    this.UserList(this.state.cityName);
  });
}
```

You could also accomplish this by inspecting prev/current state in [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Please note if you take this approach: if you ever update the `cityName` state item within `UserList` it will cause an infinite loop.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevState.cityName !== this.state.cityName) {
      this.UserList(this.state.cityName);
   }
}
```